# Cast of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'const UInt8 *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') to 'NSData *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, pebble-watch

ok I'm completely new to Obj-C and iOS. I'm just trying out a DataLogging example for the Pebble watch on iOS and changing a few things to log the accelerometer reading.

I have this function:

```
- (BOOL)dataLoggingService:(PBDataLoggingService *)service hasByteArrays:(const UInt8 *const)data numberOfItems:(UInt16)numberOfItems forDataLoggingSession:(PBDataLoggingSessionMetadata *)sessionMetadata{

    //NSString *log = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", data]; <-- this line compiles but display garbage on the view. So I try to use the line below.

    NSString *log = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; <-- this line gave build error as in the post title

    [self addLogLine:log];

    // We consumed the data, let the data logging service know:
    return YES;
}
```

So any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your error: it is telling you that cannot take a pointer to something which isn't an Objective-C object - you have a pointer to `UInt8` - simply cast it to a pointer to an Objective-C object - `NSData` in your case as ARC (the Objective-C memory collector) doesn't know how to treat the result. You address this, if possible, with a *bridge cast* which tells ARC how to handle it. However in your case its not possible as you can't just cast an `UInt8 *` to an `NSData *` - the two refer to totally different things.

At a guess your method is passed a pointer to a sequence of bytes (`hasByteArrays:`) and the number of bytes in the sequence (`numberOfItems`), if that is correct then the method you are after is `initWithBytes:length:encoding:`, this method directly takes a pointer to a byte sequence. E.g.:

```
NSString *log = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data
                                         length:numberOfItems
                                       encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: upvoted as a token of thanks for your help. I'm still getting garbage displayed on the view, changing to UTF8 encoding crashed the app. If I do this: `for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; ++i) { NSString *log = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%hhu", data[i]]; [self addLogLine:log]; }` it works and displays accelerometer data. Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like you have byte *unsigned numeric values* not characters at all. Converting random byte values to characters will produce random mess. What is your aim? If you want to keep the bytes in an Obj-C object to access them later use an `NSData` object constructed with `dataWithBytes:length:`. If you're trying to get a textual representation of them then your `for` loop is the way to go. You can create `log` as an `NSMutableString` before the loop and call `appendFormat:` inside the loop. Then after the loop you'll have a textual representation of the bytes as a string of hex in `log`.

Comment: you're right those bytes are `x,y,z uint16_t` from this [AccelData struct](http://developer.getpebble.com/2/api-reference/group___accelerometer_service.html#struct_accel_data) and they're little_endians and I'm trying to log them to a text file. So may be `NSMutableString` is the way to go but not `string of hex`.

Comment: My bad on the hex, you're using "u" format. If logging is your goal rather than create a string do what you were doing, but throw in a newline at regular intervals as well. If they are `uint16_t` then cast your pointer to `uint16_t *` and read them as that. You can make your code swap the bytes *if needed* by using `CFSwapInt16LittleToHost`

Answer (score 0):

Try with below approach:

```
- (BOOL)dataLoggingService:(PBDataLoggingService *)service hasByteArrays:(const UInt8 *const)data numberOfItems:(UInt16)numberOfItems forDataLoggingSession:(PBDataLoggingSessionMetadata *)sessionMetadata{

     NSString *log = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char *)data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [self addLogLine:log];

    // We consumed the data, let the data logging service know:
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. UTF8 encoding crashed the app, changed to `encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding` works but still display garbage.